# Problem in derivation of the volume of a sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry

I tried to find the formula for the volume of a sphere using calculus, so I took a sphere of radius $R$ and partitioned it into infinitely many circles that start from radius $r$ of 0 up to $R$ and to 0 again, such that the sum of their areas makes up the volume of the sphere. Then, I noticed this is $2\int_{0}^{R} \pi r^2dr$ which works out to be $2\pi r^3 \over 3$, which is just the volume of a sphere divided by 2

Where was I wrong?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afjHpHRdPFo

Comment: To increase the radius from $r$ to $r+dr$ doesn't involve translating the circle through a distance $dr$ orthogonal to its plane, so the volume thereby swept out isn't $\pi r^2dr$. Since $x^2+r^2=R^2\implies dx=-\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$, your strategy should write the volume as $2\int_0^R\frac{\pi r^3dr}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}$, which is indeed $\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}$ (see if you can prove it).

Comment: You've find volume of figure made of two cones with common base. Volume of rotation body is $\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \pi r(z)^2 dz$, because every disk has thickness $dz$ which can be different with $dr$. In your case $dz=dr$ which means $r=a+z$, which describes cone, not sphere. For sphere one needs to use $r=\sqrt{R^2-z^2}$ which leads to $V=2 \int_0^R \pi (R^2-z^2) dz$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct sweeping formula by circles (disks) is $$2\int_0^R \pi(R^2-r^2)dr.$$
You sweep by disks from $0$ to $R$ for half ball.

Or you may try sweeping by concentric spheres: $\int_0^R 4\pi\rho^2d\rho$.